# Splitting LESS output into two files - variable and constant

Tags: css, less

I'm using a great number of variables in my LESS implementation, however there are obviously many rules that are hard coded. The variables are defined on compile by a LESS file containing my style definitions.

Is it possible to split all of the CSS rules output by LESS into variable parts and constant parts, without manually creating two separate files?

So:

```
@myColour: white;
.foo {
   background-colour: @myColour;
   width: 120px;
}
```

becomes two files:

```
.foo {
   background-colour: white;
}
```

and

```
.foo {
   width: 120px;
}
```

This way if the theme changes, only the variables need to be reloaded.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: This should not become 2 files, or even 2 rules. What less parser are you using ? The code above is not 2 files, but 2 rules, otherwise it would be style1.css & style2.css

Comment: I know this is the case, my question was if it was possible to break the single rule into two files based on how it was generated - hard coded or off a variable.

Comment: I don't see the point of this - the reason less contains variables is to achieve exactly what the ends of the means of your question is : to make changing themes etc easier. Why don't you store all your variables in a separate file - and @import 'vars.less' it

Comment: The question was about the output CSS being handled efficiently. Variables make it easy to change the theme, but then you still have 2 massive files - theme.blue.css and theme.green.css for example as a result. Ideally you want a theme.static.css to hold anything that does not change, to prevent the users downloading superfluous code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Short Answer: No

**"Without *manually* creating two separate files?" (emphasis added), the answer is "No."**

You, the programmer, would have to code up two separate files , one that contains the variable calls, then one that contains the "hard coded" info (although, see UPDATE below). But I would not recommend that, as it would be hard to maintain (as far as seeing what is going on with the two different `.foo` entries in two different files). That's probably why you were hoping to split them *after* you coded (automatically), but this is just not possible to instruct LESS to output the variable property values to one file and the hard coded to another, at least, not automatically...

### UPDATE: The Closest I Could Get

If I understand what you want, you want one file to code in, having the various selectors defined once, but having the properties able to split into a file of css that is variable controlled and therefore that file updated regularly, and one that is static (or "hard coded") that is rarely updated. Here is the closest I could come to coding for that. It is certainly not automatic, but does offer some "consistency" in how it functions.

Consider...

**LESS Variables and Master files**

```css
// assume this is your variables file (variables.less)
@myColour: white;

// assume this is a master coding file, but it keeps all the properties
// "hidden" in nested mixins labled props()
// This file imports your variables.less file
// Note that the @file variable is NOT in the variables.less file, but
// is in the particular files used to split the code.
// We will call this file master.less

@import variables.less;

.foo {
  .props() when (@file = var), (@file = all) {
    background-colour: @myColour;
  }
  .props() when (@file = static), (@file = all) {
    width: 120px;
  }
  & > p.nested {
    .props() when (@file = var), (@file = all) {
       background-colour: @myColour;
    }
    .props() when (@file = static), (@file = all) {
       margin: 1em;
    }
    .props(); // call the props, each nesting needs its own props() call.
  }
  .props(); // call the props
}
```

**Generate LESS Static File**

```css
// Assume this is your desired static only file, called staticCSS.less
// It has imported the master coding file to access mixins
// and all code is produced by setting the local @file variable in it

@import master.less;
@file: static; // only static css will output
```

*CSS Static File Output*

```css
.foo {
  width: 120px;
}
.foo > p.nested {
  margin: 1em;
}
```

**Generate LESS Variable Controlled File**

```css
// Assume this is your desired variable controlled file, called variableCSS.less
// It has imported the master coding file to access mixins
// and all code is produced by setting the local @file variable in it

@import master.less;
@file: var; // only variable css will output
```

*CSS Variable Controlled File Output*

```css
.foo {
  background-colour: #ffffff;
}
.foo > p.nested {
  background-colour: #ffffff;
}
```

**Generate All Properties**

For testing purposes, or just to better see the total combined output of the files, I set the above mixins to all be called if `@file: all` was set, so you could do this in either of the files while testing:

```css
@import master.less;
@file: all; //all css will output
```

*CSS Variable Controlled File Output*

```css
.foo {
  background-colour: #ffffff;
  width: 120px;
}
.foo > p.nested {
  background-colour: #ffffff;
  margin: 1em;
}
```

**The class is still fully usable as a mixin itself, or extendable (LESS 1.4)**

Adding the following works (making it for `@file: static` here):

```css
.test {.foo }
.test2 {&:extend(.foo all);}
```

*CSS Output*

```css
.foo,
.test2 {
  width: 120px;
}
.foo > p.nested,
.test2 > p.nested {
  margin: 1em;
}
.test {
  width: 120px;
}
.test > p.nested {
  margin: 1em;
}
```

Comment: Wow thanks for this. You understood my reasonings correct - I don't want a big CSS file that has to be redownloaded despite being 90% the same when the user changes their theme. I also do not want to maintain two separate files that must have matching rule structures. Your solution seems like alot of extra code, but it gets the job done. Thanks!

Comment: It would be a lot of extra code and could still run into some unforeseen challenges. If 90% of your code is static, then perhaps only doing the above solution for those selectors that have both would keep the extra code down. So all selectors with both split into the above type files, but then you have a third file of selectors that never use a variable. You would end up with one file regularly updating, and _two_ static files that rarely update (the one split off, and then the one purely static).